# iPhone Core Data Generated Model Files and Custom Code

Tags: iphone, versioning, models

After I've generated the interface/implementation files for entities of a model file in XCode, I've not found a way to keep any custom code (validation methods, etc...) I've added to those generated files, given the scenario where I've added an attribute to a model entity and need to re-generate the interface/implementation files.  Does anyone know of a way to make this happen? I've just been doing the copy/paste shuffle, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're only talking about adding methods, and not new instance variables, I'd recommend using [Objective C categories](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html) to add additional behavior to your model classes. Here's a [blog post](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/core_data_code_generation) along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.com/mogenerator/), which uses the [Generation Gap](http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/gg.html) design pattern to prevent your customizations from being overwritten when the code is re-generated.